# How to read XHTML file tags using Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I want to read XHTML tags and text separately using objective C.

what approach I have to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an XML parser like `NSXMLParser`.

Comment: thanks Ole,
Parsing is bit slow, is it not possible by using NSFileHandle or any other approach.

Comment: @ashish: reading the XHTML tags from a file is the definition of parsing. There's no other way to separate them than to parse the file to discover which elements are tags and which are text. You do _not_ want to try implementing this yourself because `NSXMLParser` is much better at handling poorly formed HTML than you are.

Comment: this code snippet is also nice.
http://rudis.net/content/2009/01/21/flatten-html-content-ie-strip-tags-cocoaobjective-c